# Cannot use assimp library in Debug build configuration

Tags: cmake, assimp

I use library *Assimp* from imported target `assimp::assimp` in my project:

```
find_package(assimp REQUIRED 5)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC assimp::assimp)
```

During link stage of build of the project in `Debug` configuration I get an error:

> src/renderer/CMakeFiles/renderer.dir/build.make:256: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.

The cause of the error is that (on Archlinux) I have no `/usr/lib/cmake/assimp-5.0/assimpTargets-debug.cmake` and corresponding line in `/usr/lib/cmake/assimp-5.0/assimpTargets.cmake`. Property `IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS` of `assimp::assimp` target have only `RELEASE` value and there is no `IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG` property, just `IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE`.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the problem it is needed to add:

```
set_target_properties(assimp::assimp PROPERTIES MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_DEBUG Release)
```

Right after `find_package`.